# Need to Delete an email message from several Lotus Notes Databases

Tags: email, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Here's my problem.  I have a list of emails with large attachments.  I'd like to delete them from the users databases.  I have full access to all the users mailboxes.

Is there a way I'd be able to use Lotus-script, or Console commands to remove the email, from the users?  I'd prefer to not go into each users mail file and delete them manually.

thanks

Comment: yes, this is easily possible with some lines of LotusScript... Just start writing an agent. And if you have CONCRETE questions regarding code, then come back. Use `NotesDatabase.Search( buildyourownsearchstring, Nothing, 0 )` to find the document(s) and `NotesDocument.Remove` to delete them...

Comment: Just be absolutely sure that your search string uniquely identifies the document before you run the agent!  The searching for the $MessageId string might be a good way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I hate to ask a question like this, but is there a guide or any documentation, on how to use the two commands above?  I'm definitely a newbie when it comes to working with lotus script.

Comment: @spilegi it is not necessary to use a script to solve your task. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To save disk space on the Domino server consider [Lotus Domino Attachment and Object Service](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/DAOS_Deployment_Guide).

There is no programming involved to solve your task.

Check this [DAOS Quick Start Guide](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/daos-quick-start-guide).